# SQL - How to order by min date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table with logs

```
PERSON ID             LOGDATE (DATETIME)
  1000                2015-10-20 10:00:00
  1000                2015-11-11 09:10:22
  2001                2015-10-11 10:22:11
```

I need to order the data by LOGDATE -DATETIME - but with only the lowest date for each ID.

```
select PERSONALID, LOGDATE from TABLE   group by PERSONALID order by
MIN(LOGDATE) DESC
```

I can GROUP by ID - ORDER BY Min DATE (each result by ID), but THE FINAL RESULT doesnt order the results by MIN DATE..

```
RESULT:
1000 ------------- 2015-10-20 10:00:00 (min date for ID=1000)
2001 ------------- 2015-10-11 10:22:11 (min date for ID=2001)
```

the right answer is:

```
RESULT:
2001 ------------- 2015-10-11 10:22:11 (min date for ID=2001)
1000 ------------- 2015-10-20 10:00:00 (min date for ID=1000)
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select PERSONALID, MIN(LOGDATE) as mindate 
from TABLE   
group by PERSONALID
order by mindate
```

Comment: hi @Darshan-Mehta - tks a lot! but didn't Works.. still the same result. (order the min for each ID, but doesnt order for the result)

Comment: hi @darshan-metha.... of course.. its the right answer - I need to order by the "most distance" date.. (Now I am confused if this date is "min" or "max".. :D ) - But, yes - You solved the problem, but for me the correct order is "BY MINDATE" (without DESC).. tks!!!

Comment: I would appreciate your acceptance to my answer if it has helped you.

Comment: hi @darshan-mehta of course! but, please edit your answer - remove the DESC - because with this I got the same results from my question. The right answer is without DESC - and then I can check this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `MIN(LOGDATE)`, not `LOGDATE`.  Selecting `LOGDATE` causes MySQL to return the value of an *indeterminate record* from within each group—see [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-handling.html) for more information.